# Insert ArrayList into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I trying to insert `ArrayList` into `MySQL`, but I only gets the last values in column selected_seats. The variable list holds value `2` and `3`. When I check MySQL, only value 3 get inserted, 2 is not inserted.

```
public void insert( String Name, String NC, String acNum, String title, String day, String time, double totalPrice, ArrayList<Integer> list) throws Exception{
            System.out.println(list);
            DatabaseConnection db=new DatabaseConnection();
            Connection connect=db.getConnection();
            String sql="Insert into user_payment(user_name,ic_number,acc_number, movie_title,movie_day,movie_time, total_price, selected_seats)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1,Name);
            ps.setString(2,NC);
            ps.setString(3,acNum);
            ps.setString(4,title);
            ps.setString(5,day);
            ps.setString(6,time);
            ps.setDouble(7,totalPrice);
            for(Integer seat : list)
            {
                ps.setInt(8,seat);
                ps.executeBatch();
            }
            ps.executeUpdate();

            connect.close();
            ps.close();

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you meant to do is call [`addBatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) inside the loop, then [`executeBatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) after the loop, and not call [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) at all.

> **`addBatch()`**
>
> Adds a set of parameters to this PreparedStatement object's batch of commands.
>
> **`executeBatch()`**
>
> Submits a batch of commands to the database for execution

Also, you have to close the `PreparedStatement` *before* closing the `Connection`. Better yet, use try-with-resources.

```
public void insert(String Name, String NC, String acNum, String title, String day, String time, double totalPrice, ArrayList<Integer> list) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(list);
    DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
    try (Connection connect = db.getConnection()) {
        String sql = "insert into user_payment (user_name, ic_number, acc_number, movie_title, movie_day, movie_time, total_price, selected_seats) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        try (PreparedStatement ps = connect.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            ps.setString(1, Name);
            ps.setString(2, NC);
            ps.setString(3, acNum);
            ps.setString(4, title);
            ps.setString(5, day);
            ps.setString(6, time);
            ps.setDouble(7, totalPrice);
            for (Integer seat : list) {
                ps.setInt(8, seat);
                ps.addBatch();
            }
            ps.executeBatch();
         }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

> Is it possible to make it insert only one row, which mean column selected_seats value has `2,3` instead create two rows ?

If the `selected_seats` column is not a numeric column as the original `setInt(8,seat)` was indicating, but a `VARCHAR` which should get a comma-separated list of seat numbers, then a batch is not needed. You then need to convert the `List<Integer>` into that comma-separated string

```
StringJoiner buf = new StringJoiner(",");
for (Integer seat : list)
    buf.add(seat.toString());
ps.setString(8, buf.toString());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

[`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) was added in Java 8. If running on earlier version, use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (Integer seat : list) {
    if (buf.length() != 0)
        buf.append(',');
    buf.append(seat);
}
ps.setString(8, buf.toString());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it insert only one row, which mean column selected_seats value has `2,3`  instead create two rows ?

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes, but then it wouldn't be an `INTEGER` column anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert seat to another table or can be insert with String type as below.

```
public void insert( String Name, String NC, String acNum, String title, String day, String time, double totalPrice, ArrayList<Integer> list) throws Exception { 
    System.out.println(list);
    DatabaseConnection db=new DatabaseConnection(); 
    Connection connect=db.getConnection(); 
    String sql="Insert into user_payment(user_name,ic_number,acc_number, movie_title,movie_day,movie_time, total_price, selected_seats)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 
    PreparedStatement ps=connect.prepareStatement(sql); 
    ps.setString(1,Name); 
    ps.setString(2,NC); 
    ps.setString(3,acNum); 
    ps.setString(4,title); 
    ps.setString(5,day); 
    ps.setString(6,time); 
    ps.setDouble(7,totalPrice); 
    String seatList = "";
    for(Integer seat : list) { 
        if(seatList.equal("")) {
            seatList = seat;
        } else {
            seatList += "," + seat;
        }
    } 
    ps.setString(8,seatList); 
    ps.executeBatch(); 
    ps.executeUpdate(); 
    connect.close(); 
    ps.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Works for me. However, it should be `seatList.equals("")`.

Comment: Don't do `string += string` in a loop. In Java 8 use a `StringJoiner`, otherwise use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I am also java begineer, thank for your sharing. :-)